# CSS change element on Navbar focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So a particular version of a general problem - the macstyle search can be pretty nifty - but it's supper annoying when combined with a dropdown menu - it's considered focus until the drop down is clicked at which point the dropdown is transitioned away from the mouse.

```
 .mac-style {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 }

.mac-style:focus{
    width: 260px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mdXqr/5/

I know I can use a :hover for elements nearby `+` or inbetween `~` , but is there anyway to specify the search bar expansion as long as anything on the navbar is focused? And to have it narrow only when an element somewhere on the page other than on the navbar is focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that a pure CSS solution would work but a small jQuery script could solve it.

If you apply a class to the search field when it is focused and then add an events for actions that would make it shrink, like clicking outside the `.navbar` and remove the class.

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbVmA/2/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(".mac-style").focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $(".not-navbar").click(function() {
        $(".mac-style").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: So there's nothing like .navbar:hover (%something%) .mac-style { width:260px }  ?

Comment: You can use `.navbar:hover .mac-style { width:260px }` to widen the search input while you hover the navbar but that will trigger as soon as the mouse is inside `.navbar`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fbVmA/3/

Comment: Funny, I tried that and assumed it only worked on a direct sibling when it didn't do anything - it turns out it was just the way i was floating th enavbar.